# Android : Actionbar Icon disappearing in UI

Tags: android

I have put two icons from Android Icon Packager for action bar. The Info Action appears brightly while the next one, Refresh Action is not appearing. I use both as holo_dark. I tried switching just the refresh action, and it appears very very dimly.

[image]

I've try reading many many stuffs I seem to find nothing about this topic.

EDIT: I have solved this problem by deleting the whole refresh icon and then remove the line

android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"

in the XML. I then re-added the icon and it works like a charm. Voted both answer for caring about my question

Answer (score 1):

Use Icon from your Android Package Opposite to Your Theme.
For eg: If you are using **Holo_Dark Theme in your Application use Holo_White Icon Set for it.**

[image]

Comment: I use Holo Light with Dark Action bar, I've tried using both holo_white and holo_dark from core_refresh icon set downloaded from Android Source. Somehow it's not working. It's like the machine keep thinking those two are the same thing

Comment: I just changed the icon to holo_dark set of discard icon. It works fine! And then I switched back to refresh and it does not work